# Create Bar Chart using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a Bar Chart using Google's jsapi, and I've downloaded the following code (with my own changes), that needs to create Bar Chart.

```
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        drawChart(AvgTimeInConference, keysSorted3);
            
        function drawChart(AvgTimeInConference, keysSorted3) {
            var DataTable=[];
            DataTable.push(['Conference', 'Average Duration']);
            
            for (var i=0; i<keysSorted3.length; i++)
            {
                if(keysSorted3[i]!=="")
                {
                    var x=[keysSorted3[i], AvgTimeInConference[keysSorted3[i]]];
                    DataTable.push(x);
                }
            }
            
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(DataTable);
            
            var options = {
                title: 'average durations length of the conferences, grouped by Conference Type',
                vAxis: {title: 'Average Duration',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
            };
            
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

The code works greate, until it gets to the line "var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(DataTable);". Data Table at this point is an array that contains the data in cells (first cell - headers, second and on are the data according to headers). When trying to use that function, the run get stuck and doesn't move on. doe's anyone has an idea why it happens? is DataTable not in the right format? Thanks!

Edit: The DataTable object from debug
[image]

Comment: The code all looks fine. If you could provide what `DataTable` looks like at the `arrayToDataTable` call, that would help in figuring out the problem.  The error happening at that line could speed up the process too

Comment: "is DataTable not in the right format", probably not, as this is where the error occurs. Please provide us how it actually looks like.

Comment: Edited the post with a screenshot :) Tnx!

Comment: I'm getting it to work flawless in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/sc1e6hfd/1/). 

Maybe  you should try to work something else out than throwing the `keysSorted3` back and forth between the `drawChart` and the rest?

Comment: I think it's because I'm not using "google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);", but calling directly to the function... what if I don't want the graph to load automatically ? I need the data in the graph to come from a file that I open, and through it get the data (what's in AvgTimeInConference, keysSorted3) - the data is dynamic...